# Поиск однокоренных слов в списке Python

Tags: python, list, список, словари, dict

Есть большой словарь. Где ключ - это ссылка на рецепт. А значение - это список ингредиентов. Пример:

`dict {'https://random.com':['банан', 'яйца', 'мука', 'картофель']}`

А есть запросы пользователя(в боте телеграм), которые я преобразую в список и сравниваю со списками в словаре и отдаю ссылку на рецепт, если есть попадание по запросу.

Так вот, многие рецепты не идут к пользователю, если нет точного попадания слов. Например,
когда пользователь ввел:

```
['картошка', 'яйцо']
```

И он не получает рецепт, хотя он подходит. Подскажите, как можно организовать проверку в этом случае? Как искать только по части слова **'карто'**, **'яйц'**? Подскажите пожалуйста хотя бы направление поиска, если не само решение. Спасибо

Comment: Возможно стоит создать таблицу ассоциаций, в которой яицо, яйцо, яиц и тп будут = яицо (одному ингридиенту)

После того, как вы определили ингридиенты - просто проверить, в каком рецепте больше совпадение с ингридиентами.

Comment: Не совсем прямой ответ, но, возможно, вам чем-то поможет `pymorphy2`.

Comment: @MichaelTetelev, pymorphy2 — морфологический анализатор, а не морфемный. Он может только в начальную форму привести слово.

Comment: @КириллМалышев да, скорее всего, конкретно это он сделать не сможет, но лишним не будет.

Comment: Есть какие-то проекты для морфемного разбора https://github.com/AlexeySorokin/NeuralMorphemeSegmentation, https://github.com/kpopov94/morpheme_seq2seq. Можно их ещё попробовать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь стоит использовать алгоритм нечёткого сравнения строк. Вот пример:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
l = ['банан', 'яйца', 'мука', 'картофель']
print(process.extractOne("картошка", l))  # ('картофель', 59)
```

Второй элемент в кортеже — число от 0 до 100, которое показывает степень похожести слов. Например, можно считать, что ингредиенты одинаковые, если их похожесть >= 50.

Для повышения качества сравнения можно привести все слова в форму без окончаний:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from nltk.stem.snowball import RussianStemmer
l = ['банан', 'яйца', 'мука', 'картофель']
stemmer  = RussianStemmer()
stem_l = [stemmer.stem(x) for x in l]  # ['бана', 'яйц', 'мук', 'картофел']
ingredient = stemmer.stem("картошка")  # 'картошк'
print(process.extractOne(ingredient, stem_l))  # ('картофел', 67)
```

Не забудьте установить необходимые библиотеки:

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
pip install nltk
```

Конечно, при таком подходе можно перепутать похожие ингредиенты. Например, посчитать что "горох" и "горошек" это одно и то же.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень интересное решение.  Пошел делать. Небольшое количество брака, как в примере с  "горох" и "горошек" не критично. Мне гораздо важнее, чтобы пользователи получали больше рецептов.

Answer (score 3):

Неплохой вариант - использовать [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) с русским словарем (pymorphy2-dict-ru) или его форк [pymorphy3](https://pypi.org/project/pymorphy3/), который, похоже, отличается только обновленными словарями. Как сказано в комментариях к вопросу, он может привести слово к начальной форме. Что и требуется: приводим все ингредиенты и сравниваем. Такой подход отлично работает в другом телеграмном боте (полнотекстовый морфологический поиск).

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё код приводить, так то совет правильный.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Надеюсь, [отсюда](https://github.com/skd/telegram-bot-help-ua-ch/blob/main/morpho_index.py) можно кое-что почерпнуть.